# Visual Studio giving generic debug errors, but gives specific errors out of debug

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I don't even know what to call this, but here's the situation - I use Visual Studio 2013 to create a Windows Forms Project. At some point, the debugger started throwing out this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

However, I happened to notice that when I run the program without debugging, and the error occurs, it gives me:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

It's not a complicated program, I'm not doing anything like multithreading or delegating yet. No matter what I try, it only gives the first error. I've gotten it when I was try to delete a file that didn't exist, when the index was out of bounds, when a control threw an error. All these errors just quoted the first one in debug mode, but the normal errors out of debug mode.

I just threw the code in another project and it works fine. Maybe it's a option in the debugging menu, but I've tried everything I could imagine. I also tried updating to VS2013 Update 4 and it still does it. Help?

Comment: Look at the InnerException.

Comment: via try/catch, right? It works fine that way too, but still doesn't tell me in the code which part is wrong, like the debug is supposed to.

Comment: Sounds like the debug .pdb is out of sync with the .exe. Try Cleaning and Rebuilding the project. Don't know if this will work but what happens if you copy the .pdb from the Release folder to the Debug folder?

Comment: I cleaned and rebuilt, same thing.

There's nothing in the release folder. Running the debug EXE outside the VS gives me the normal error, running it inside so I can find out why gives me the generic. I've never run it via release.

Comment: VS2013 Acted funny for me too. I reverted to using VS2012. It would fail compilations with error but there wouldn't be any specific error. Same project in VS2012 would compile with no issues

Comment: The debugger tells you about the exception that was unhandled, which was TargetInvocationException.  Without the debugger attached, the Application.ThreadException event handler deals with the unhandled exception.  Which knows to look at the InnerException.  The best way to debug is to make the debugger stop when the inner exception is thrown.  Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: I've noticed that VS 2013 launches several MSBuild processes which sometimes become orphaned.  This seems to be exacerbated by switching Release/Debug or x64/x86.  The orphaned MsBuild processes lock up random files causing weird behavior.  Exit your VS 2013, launch Task manager and kill any MSBuild processes that are still running.

Answer (score 0):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

A TargetInvocationException is a wrapper around the actual exception.
 "The client application's event-handler delegate should check the Error property; otherwise, the property will raise a TargetInvocationException"

Try returning a try catch and get the ex.InnerException
and see why it is giving this error

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

try this as well

```
try {
   //here you read the arguments and pass to a variable
}
catch(System.IndexOutOfRangeException) {
     //other codepart
}
```

Hope this helps